# How to set an initial offset for Animated in Reac Native

Tags: react-native

I have an image and I want to translate it horizontally from `imageWidth` to `-imageWidth` on a loop, but I want to have it starts at `0` for the first loop. I've tried to `setValue(0)` right after setting the timing but it still starts from `imageWidth`. The code I have now:

```
this.translateValue = new Animated.Value(0)

translate() {
    this.translateValue.setValue(this.backgroundImageWidth)
    Animated.timing(
      this.translateValue,
      {
        toValue: -this.backgroundImageWidth,
        duration: 20000,
        easing: Easing.linear
      }
    ).start(()=>this.translate())
  }

 componentDidMount() {
    this.translate()
    this.translateValue.setValue(0)
    ...
 }

render() {
return(
 <Animated.Image
  style={{
   flex: 1,
   position: 'absolute',
   left: this.translateValue,
  }}
  resizeMode={Image.resizeMode.cover}
  source={this.backgroundImage}
  />
)
```

Comment: shouldnt you call `this.translateValue.setValue(0)` before you call `translate` in your didmount method?